# How do I increment a value with leading zeroes in Perl?

Tags: perl

It's the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587647/how-to-increment-a-value-with-leading-zeroes), but using Perl!

I would like to iterate over a value with just one leading zero.

The equivalent in shell would be:

```
for i in $(seq -w 01 99) ; do echo $i ; done
```

Comment: Obviously, there is more that one way to do it ;) I'll go with the most detailed one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since the leading zero is significant, presumably you want to use these as strings, not numbers.  In that case, there is a different solution that does not involve sprintf:

```
for my $i ("00" .. "99") {
    print "$i\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 That's awesome.  I didn't know you could use the range operator with strings like that.

Answer (score 11):

Try something like this:

```
foreach (1 .. 99) {
   $s = sprintf("%02d",$_);
   print "$s\n";
}
```

The `..` is called the [Range Operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) and can do different things depending on its context.  We're using it here in a list context so it counts up by ones from the left value to the right value.  So here's a simpler example of it being used; this code:

```
@list = 1 .. 10; 
print "@list";
```

has this output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

The [`sprintf` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) allows us to format output. The format string `%02d` is broken down as follows:

- `%` - start of the format string
- `0` - use leading zeroes
- `2` - at least two characters wide
- `d` - format value as a signed integer.

So `%02d` is what turns `2` into `02`.

Comment: +1.  Unlike the accepted answer, this solution works on any type of number set and no matter how they are defined: "0.00", "1/4", "12.34e-56", etc..

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%02d\n",$_) foreach (1..20)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print  foreach  ("001" .. "099")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider to use sprinft to format $i according to your requirements. E.g. `printf '<%06s>', 12;` prints `<000012>`.
Check [Perl doc about sprinft](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) in case you are unsure.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach $i (1..99) {printf "%02d\n", $i;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if we're golfing, why not:

```
say for "01".."99"`
```

(assuming you're using 5.10 and have done a `use 5.010` at the top of your program, of course.)

And if you do it straight from the shell, it'd be:

```
perl -E "say for '01'..'99'"
```